# Proof that $C_{0} ^{\infty}$ bounded functions are dense in $L^{1} (\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

We have been told that functions $C^{\infty}$,and with a compact support are dense in $L^{1} (\mathbb{R})$. While I can prove them singularly (except for the functions $C^{\infty}$), I cannot find, given $f \in L^{1}$ a succession $\{f_n \}$ that satisfies both of them. Also, I was wondering if these kind of subspaces (as well as other dense subspaces like step functions for instance) are also dense in every $L^{p}$, and (if not) if there is a standard method for checking out if a particular dense subspace of $L^{1}$ is dense for other $L^{p}$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What does 'find a succession that satisfies all three of them' mean? Three of what? What do you mean by a succession?

Comment: @copper.hat A succession of functions that is $C^{\infty}$, defined in a compact set and bounded. I will edit to explain it better. Also, the functions have to be bounded as they are continuous over a compact set

Comment: A *very* rough outline of one proof: (1) Show that the characteristic function of a bounded interval can be approximated in $L^1$ norm by a $C^\infty$ function of compact support. (2) Show that the characteristic function of a Lebesgue measurable set of finite measure can be approximated by linear combinations of characteristic functions of intervals. (3) Conclude that any integrable simple function can be approximated by $C^\infty$ functions. (4) From there, the step to arbitrary $L^1$ functions is easy.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen If I have undrestood well, I should use the fact that simple functions are dense in $L^1$, show that I can approximate every simple function with a $C^{\infty} _0$ one, and then conclude. If I managed to prove the point (1) I am pretty sure I can manage to go on without any problem, but how should I prove that? I was thinking, maybe using Stone-Weierstrass could be of some help?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Ok I have found how it was proven to me, I thought I didn't have those notes. However, it looks like my teacher used convolution, functions that look like gauss bell and the fact that differentiation "goes into" the convolution (I mean $ \partial (f*g)=\partial f *g$). It looks a bit tricky though...

Comment: Check out [Bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) on Wikipedia. If $\Psi$ is the function defined there, let $g(x)=C\int_{-\infty}^{x-1}\Psi(t)\,dt$; then $g$ is $C^\infty$, $g(x)=0$ for $x<0$, and $g(x)$ is a positive constant for $x>2$. Choose the constant factor $C$ to make that constant equal to $1$. Now, for $\varepsilon>0$, approximate the characteristic function of an interval $[a,b]$ by $g((x-a)/\varepsilon)g((b-x)/\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Ok I think I got it now. You use the fact that it regularizes the convolution making it $C^{\infty}$ and then Fubini-Tonelli theorem to get rid of it. Right?